# Formatting Literal parameters of a C# code snippet

Tags: c#, code-generation, code-snippets

Is there any way that I can change how a Literal of a code snippet renders when it is used in the code that the snippet generates?

Specifically I'd like to know if I can have a literal called say, $PropertyName$ and then get the snippet engine to render "_$PropertyName$ where the first character is made lowercase.

I can't afford R#.  Please help :)

Comment: See my suggestion to [Add scripting to code snippets (T4 + Roslyn)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5805587-add-scripting-to-code-snippets-t4-roslyn). Unfortunately I got no response to this suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no way. Snippets offer amazingly limited support for [transformation functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312(VS.80).aspx) as you can see.

You have to stick with the VS standard solution, which is to write two literals: one for the property name, and the other for the member variable name.

Comment: I'm afraid I've not.  I ended up buying a personal license of R#

Comment: [As of Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312(v=vs.120).aspx), the three available functions are still only: `GenerateSwitchCases`, `ClassName`, and `SimpleTypeName`.

Comment: **APPALLING!!!** Is there a Visual Studio UserVoice entry for this? I'd give my votes for additional functions. I'm really perplexed how come they didn't even think of the other string-manipulating functions to add. Casing included.

Comment: There is now: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/34816990-add-camelcase-transformation-to-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 8):

You can enter a upper first letter, then a property name, then a lower first letter. Try this snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>Notifiable Property</Title>
    <Author>Nikolay Makhonin</Author>
    <Shortcut>propn</Shortcut>
    <Description>Property With in Built Property Changed method implementation.</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
        <Literal>
            <ID>Type</ID>
            <Default>Type</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>P</ID>
            <Default>P</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>roperty</ID>
            <Default>ropertyName</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>p</ID>
            <Default>p</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>Ownerclass</ID>
            <ToolTip>The owning class of this Property.</ToolTip>
            <Function>ClassName()</Function>
            <Default>Ownerclass</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
      <![CDATA[#region $P$$roperty$

        private Field<$Type$> _$p$$roperty$;
        public static readonly string $P$$roperty$PropertyName = GetPropertyName(() => (($Ownerclass$)null).$P$$roperty$);
        public $Type$ $P$$roperty$
        {
            get { return _$p$$roperty$; }
            set { Set(ref _$p$$roperty$, value); }
        }

        #endregion

]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Answer (score 6):

a "fix" may be to use a prefix in the naming or the member variable, i.e.:

```
string m_$name$;
string $name$
{
 get{return m_$name$;}
 set{m_$name$=value;}
};
```

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't allow you to change the casing of $name$ to make it camelCase. (Typically people use `"_property"` as the backing for a property named `"Property"`, etc.  Also "m_" is super deprecated... since like vb6...? please don't ever use it).

Comment: Sorry for necro-commenting, but "m_" is not deprecated at all. It's a great practice which I think should be used more. Unless you and anybody else never ever have to read that code again - yeah, because that never happened.