# Can visual studio suggest variable names?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Eclipse can automatically create (or suggest) variable names. For instance if I have a class named MyClass and i want to create an object from it, MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); In Eclipse after class name (MyClass) i hit ctrl+space key and Eclipse automaticly suggests name for the variable (myClass). Is there any similar feature in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio does not do what you're describing, but it is possible to get this functionality through extensions. I know [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this (and much more), so you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are two free options I see:

1) Free Visual Studio extension [.net AutoCode](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/48eeb43f-cb46-4680-b7df-11e73cf894ca).
Just install it and type in the code:
`MyClass i`
and press Ctrl + Enter. AutoCode will replace `MyClass i` with
`MyClass myClass = new MyClass();`

2) You could write a code snippet and save it with, say newvar.snippet name, to custom snippets folder (usually C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio NNNN\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>newvar</Title>
      <Author>
      </Author>
      <Description>Declares varible with the same name as its type name.</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>newvar</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Imports>
        <Import>
        </Import>
      </Imports>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>type</ID>
          <ToolTip>type</ToolTip>
          <Default>type</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$type$ $type$ = new $type$($end$);]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

When you restart your VS and type in the code
`newvar`
and then press Tab key twice
VS will insert
`type type = new type();`
with first "type" word highlited. Type in appropriate class name `MyClass` (autocompletion is enabled) and press Enter key twice. VS will replace code:
`MyClass MyClass = new MyClass();`
Unfortunatly, variable would get the name of its class (see [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164729/2164198) and [suggestion on visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9279405-add-camelcase-transformation-for-snippet-variables)).
But it's very easy to fix (improper variable case) manually.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not suggest variable names, but it should complete most other things.

For example, if you do `MyClass myClass =` it should pop up an IntelliSense box with `new MyClass();` in it.
It does have some useful things, however, that can quickly create things for you. For example, if you type `class` and press TAB twice, it will create a class template, or if you type `ctor` or `mbox` it will create a constructor or `MessageBox.Show()` call, respectively.